# Default template is broken on new Mezzanine install.

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I had a little trouble even getting Mezzanine to install and now that I have the css seems broken. I have looked all over the web and can't seem to find out where my mistake is. The instructions I followed are here:

https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/python/installing-and-configuring-mezzanine-on-shared-hosting

My site is as at the following link:

http://wakeofthetranscendent.a2hosted.com/

I really am not even sure of what code to post because I have no idea where the problem is. I was able to get it running using runserver on my laptop but as my a2 account is shared I don't have that option.

Comment: The location of the css is probably not "/static/css/something.css". You should change that to a relative path to locate it on the servers of "a2hosted".

Comment: @----- [~/public_html/wake/static]# ls
admin/  css/  filebrowser/  fonts/  grappelli/  img/  js/  mezzanine/  robots.txt  test/

@----- [~/public_html/wake/static]# ls css
bootstrap.css  bootstrap-rtl.css  bootstrap-theme.css  mezzanine.css

There is a css file in static and it has files in it but thank you for your suggestion.